# ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG not working API Lollipop

Tags: android-intent, broadcastreceiver, headset

I'm using this code for detect headphones plug/unplug, works fine in API >= 24 but when try it in API 21, 22, 23 crash or don't detects anything. You can help me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private MusicIntentReceiver myReceiver;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myReceiver = new MusicIntentReceiver();
}

@Override public void onResume() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    super.onResume();
}

private class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            switch (state) {
            case 0:
                Log.d(TAG, "Headset is unplugged");
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.d(TAG, "Headset is plugged");
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "I have no idea what the headset state is");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolve! just don't works on android emulators, on a real phone works fine thanks!